# Creating a view from output of pl sql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, view, procedure

I have a pl sql procedure which returns me the orders and their statuses. I need only stuck orders, so I have written some logic in the pl sql stored procedure. Now, I want to create a view from the output of this pl sql procedure. Is this possible? If yes, then how? Here is the procedure code example.

```
create or replace procedure stuck_order 
is
  id    table_order.id%type;
  state table_status.state%type;
  count number(8,2);
  cursor cur1 is (select id 
                    from table_order);
  cursor cur2 is (select state 
                    from table_status);
begin
  open cur1
  loop 
    fetch cur1 into id;
    exit when cur1%notfound;
    count := 0;
    open cur2;
    loop
      fetch cur2 into state;
      exit when cur2%notfound;
      if(state = 1)
      then
        count := count + 1;
      end if;
    end loop
    close cur2;
    if(count = 0)
      dbms_output.Put.line(id || 'stuck')
    end if;
  end loop;
  close cur1;
end;
```

Comment: "Picture" is worth a thousand words. Where is your code?

Comment: I have added please check

Comment: No, you cannot create a view based on this procedure. What you can do is to turn your procedure into a query(because right now I see no reason to use a procedural code for that), or a table function(if needed) and then create a view.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov by table function you mean pl sql function?

Comment: Yes,  PL/SQL function that returns a result set (can be queried as a table using `TABLE()` operator), not a scalar value. Besides, the logic doesn't make much sense - you just loop over result sets returned by the second cursor as many times as many rows returned by the first one without any filtering(or join immitation).